# LEN function in Excel not returning a numerical value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm having a strange issue here with Excel. I'm working with a custom datetime format in one column...

`9/1/2017  12:02:01 AM`

This is cell C2. However, using LEN on this cell gives me this...

`1900-01-15 00:00:00`

I've tried changing the format to General, or Text, and messing around with some custom datetimes, but it doesn't help. I will get the same answer. My goal here is to use this as an exercise and trim the date and time, putting them in separate columns. This spreadsheet was originally created using Google Sheets, not sure if that might explain it?

UPDATE: Ok, so about 1 minute after posting this I think I figured it out? I used LEN in the column to the left of column C, so B. I had been using column D. For some reason, column B returned the numerical value. Obviously I'm very new to Excel. I didn't think column placement mattered in this case. Why does it?

Comment: LEN returns that length of a string or number.  The Date is stored as a number(Integer as number of days since 12/31/1899 and time is the decimal part per day).  It will have 15 significant digits.  The LEN is returning `15`, the number of significant digits.  IF you just want the date then use `=INT(A1)` and format it as you would like.  For Time we can use `=MOD(A1,1)` and format that as the correct time format.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner. Will be saving this & referring back in the future I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have formatted the result to be shown as a date.

Remember, dates are simply really large numbers. So, what has happened here is that you get the correct result from `LEN()`, but then you have formatted this result to be interpreted as a date.

The date seems to indicate the result was 15. In dates, this is 15 full days from 1900 January 1st.

**So, you just have to change the format of that cell from a date, to be a number** :)